# python passing binary file through rabbitmq

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am trying to pass binary file through rabbitmq by pika (python driver of rabbitmq)

```
channel.exchange_declare(exchange=exchange_name,type="fanout",durable=True)
channel.queue_declare(queue=queue_name,durable=True)
channel.queue_bind(exchange=exchange_name,queue=queue_name,routing_key="#")
channel.confirm_delivery()
confirmed = channel.basic_publish(exchange=exchange_name,routing_key="",body=data)
```

data is my binary file. I would like to pass file name as a parameter so I can know what file I has queued to rabbimq.

How would I do it?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this. If you can serialized your data you can send it as a regular message.  So if you can load your data file as and object you can serialize it to text using yaml XML or Json. And send the serialized text as the message. And deserialize at the consumer end. Other wise you could treat the body as just an array of bytes. A string is and array of bytes so the message will be meaningless as text but will be th byte represntation of you file.

A different approach would be to not send the file at all. Rather each message is a link so the consumer knows where to find the file. It can then read or download the file.